# Looking for a way to get file/folder permissions equivalent to ICACLS.EXE

Tags: delphi, winapi, icacls, dacl

I'm using Delphi 11.3 Alexandria. How do I get file/folder permissions on Windows?

On a command line, I can use `icacls /save`, but would prefer a direct call. I get the below result, which I can use with `/Restore` and apply again:

```
Abc
D:(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIID;0x1200a9;;;BU)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you even search the [WinAPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/getting-information-from-an-acl) yet?

Comment: [`GetFileSecurity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-getfilesecurityw) or [`GetNamedSecurityInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve DACLs with [GetNamedSecurityInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow) or [Low-level Security Descriptor Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/low-level-security-descriptor-functions) and [Low-level ACL and ACE Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/low-level-acl-and-ace-functions).

Then you can list ACEs for example [dcomperm](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/Win7Samples/com/fundamentals/dcom/dcomperm/ListAcl.Cpp#L187).

And according to [Security Descriptor String Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-string-format),

> The **ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor** function
> converts a security descriptor to a string format. You can use the
> string format to store or transmit the security descriptor.

Comment: Do you have telepathy ? I did not ask, was struggling with it. Thanks !!